# How to periodically render Flask webpage

Tags: python, flask, scheduler

I want to periodically refresh my Flask webpage. Currently, it renders once but doesn't periodically render. I first configure the webdriver and then scrape data from a url. But once it opens on my browser I'm not sure how to periodically render automatically.

I have tried using APScheduler (sched.addjob()), but it hasn't worked. This is the code in my app.py file

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from functions import *
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
import pyautogui


app = Flask(__name__)
sched = APScheduler()

def convertPagesRemainingToPercentage(str):
    ret = ''

    for each in str:
        if each.isdigit():
            ret += each

    return round(int(ret) / 2400 * 100)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    # make sure to add all possible colours across all printers to this array
    colours = ['Black', 'Photo Black', 'Matte Black', 'Gray', 'Cyan', 'Magenta', 'Yellow']

    # for every newly-added printer, add it into the below dictionary
    statuses = {
        'Receiving Desk': scrape1('http://11.11.11.11/'),
        'Centre': scrape2('http://22.22.22'),
        'Main': scrape3('https://33.33.33.33/'),
        
    }

   
    numericData = {}

    for printer, obj in statuses.items():
        numericData[printer] = {}

        for colour, val in obj.items():
            try:
                if printer == 'Finance Office':
                    numericData[printer][colour] = convertPagesRemainingToPercentage(val)
                    
                else:
                    numericData[printer][colour] = int(val[:-1])
            
            except:
                numericData[printer][colour] = None
    
    # renders webpage after all scraping is completed
    return render_template('template.html', statuses=statuses, colours=colours, numericData=numericData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Please let me know what changes I can make to the code. Thanks

Comment: You can use the "Refresh" meta element, which should work with most browsers. Check this out https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/how-to-refresh-a-page-in-an-interval-without-javascript/